# Double colon in class name and RubyMine complaints about short name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I have the following autogenerated controller in
**conrollers/v2/base_controller.rb**.

```
class V2::BaseController < ApplicationController
end
```

It was generated by [Versionist gem](https://github.com/bploetz/versionist). I am trying to make a controller inherited from `V2::BaseController`. I wrote

```
class V2::MainController < V2::BaseController
  def index
    render :text => 'abcde'
  end
end
```

It works fine and I can see my text rendered in browser. However, RubyMine IDE complains that the class name `V2` in `V2::MainController` is too short and I should rename the class.

I am confused because I thought that `V2::` means that we define a new class inside `V2` module. If I am wrong, then why does RubyMine ignore the same problem with `BaseController`?

**UPD**: RubyMine complaint

[image: RubyMine complaint]

Comment: What happened where you defined `V2`? Is this Rails-specific?

Comment: @sawa I haven't defined it. http://pastebin.com/F0Js7ue9 - search results for V2 (omitted logs from ack-grep output)

Comment: @sawa I updated my question with a screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RubyMine uses [`reek`](https://github.com/troessner/reek) for code smell detection.

Warning it's giving you is called [Uncommunicative Module Name](https://github.com/troessner/reek/blob/master/docs/Uncommunicative-Module-Name.md).

> Uncommunicative Module Name checks for:
>
> 1. 1-character names
> 2. any name ending with a number

In your case warning was caused with `2` in `V2`. Even for `Version2` it would be the same.

But it's actually only a recommendation. Ruby works fine with this code.

Answer (score 2):

Nah, it's just a notice for you as a programmer. Short variable names are usually cryptic and less intention-revealing, so it's a nice check to have, but is definitely not a required one.

I think that `V2` is perfectly fine for your case, <s>but if you're still concerned, just rename it to `Version2` to make Rubymine happy. I don't know if it will be still compatible with the gem you use.</s> it seems Rubymine doesn't like [any variable with a number on the end](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32801316/273444).

> But why does IDE show the notice only for MainController?

I can think about 2 options here:

1. It's some glitch in RubyMine indexing. Or maybe it was made this way not to spam your file tree with red underlines (one is actually enough for you to notice that). Try restarting the IDE and see if it goes away.
2. RubyMine can't find definition of `V2` module, because `V2` in `class V2::MainController` is a reference to defined module somewhere, and not its definition. Solution: create the empty module and see if your warning goes away.

> app/controllers/v2.rb

```
module V2
end
```

Comment: But why does IDE show the notice only for MainController?

Comment: `Version2` is still "bad" for RubyMine.